# Can you construct objects as folders that contains text files？

Tags: python, string, list, file, class

I am writing a program that includes constructing folders of multiple text files (and also includes editing these files, so it is hard to treat one file just as a string). Now I am thinking of two ways:

1. Using a nested list of strings, while the biggest list is the folder.
2. Using class, while each object is initialized with these text files. 
   However, the second one I don't know how to accomplish.

Which one would you recommend, or is there some other ways that I can use?
If the second one makes sense, could you enlight me how to do it?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way (depending on what exactly you want to do with the objects once you have them) might be to create a dictionary with the folder names as keys and the values as lists of the filenames:

```
folders = {'folderA': ['file1', 'file2', ...], 'folderB': ['file1',...], ...}
```

Comment: I see, thank you :) Just a quick add-on -- the 'file1' can be replaced with a list like `['file1part1', 'file1part2', ['file1part3_1', 'file1part3_2']...]` right?

Comment: Also, is the reason why not using a class just that it is more complicated or that it is not doable? Thank you!

Comment: You could do it with a class, this is just simpler. You can do quite a lot with Python's built-in containers like lists and dictionaries. Yes, you could nest the filename lists if that's what you need.